# Sencha test timeout, waiting

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm starting with Sencha test and trying run some simple tests. 
I start with simple webpage and it works. Now when I create simple form i ext, and try to test it using localhost, I have communicate

> Failed: Timeout waiting for target (input[name="name"]) to be available

I'm doing it exactly same way just change the elements names, so it should work.
I know that it can be cos page loading is too long so I try add function for wait (both with time and until it find element), nothing helps.

Any ideas?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I'm just looking for way to delay searching elements until page load..

Comment: 'describe("formularz.js", function() {
    it("should pass", function() {
        ST.element('input[name="name"]')
            .focus()
            .type('Pat');
//other elements like the first one
    });
});'

Comment: Ok, that was my bad. I was looking for elements when it should be components. Sorry for trouble but as I say, I just started.